# Tools for prototyping iPad applications

Tags: ipad

(I asked in stackoverflow but repeat it here)

I would like to build a GUI prototype for an `iPad` application. The prototype can use static data (e.g. an xml file) but should look good and be fully functional, i.e. support user gestures, etc.

Obviously, I can program it in `Objective-C`. I wonder if I can use any other tool to build such a GUI easier. Does such a tool exist ?

Maybe I should use a GUI builder to build a "static" GUI and add some `Objective-C` code to make it react on user gestures. Does it make sense ?

Comment: I think that one of the main aspects of prototyping is to not allow any code in the application, including gestures. Therefore, it may be difficult to find such an application.

Answer (score 1):

Balsamiq: http://balsamiq.com/

Answer (score 1):

[Interface](http://lesscode.co.nz/interface) lets you make the mockup in the iOS device, and looks and acts like a real app. The mockup can then be exported to xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [iMockups](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/imockups-for-ipad/id364885913?mt=8) for my prototyping purposes for several months now and have been pleased with it so far.

The only downside can also be its greatest strength (depending on your needs): it is designed to be flexible. For instance, you can do quick web mockups as well in the app. Since it isn't specialized, you don't get features such as exporting code for Xcode to use, but the added flexibility can be a great boon.

Answer (score 1):

If you're a Mac user I would highly recommend using [Travis Isaacs's](http://travisisaacs.com/) very cool [**Wireframe Toolkit for Keynote**](http://keynotekungfu.com/). Keynote provided the ability to link areas in your mockup to other slides and use a lot of the transitions and animations that are very close to their iOS counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

[WireframeSketcher](http://wireframesketcher.com) comes with dedicated stencils for iPad applications. You can use links for simple interactivity. You can even test your prototype on iPad by exporting it to HTML that you can put online via Dropbox.